# how to nest a for loop to subplot a scatter on iris data?

Tags: python, for-loop, subplot

I am trying to write a 4 by 4 scatter matrix using for loop and subplot functions. The data is iris. I have run this code but nothing is getting returned. Please review it and advise,what went wrong, thanks.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
iris = datasets.load_iris()
 
X=iris.data
Y=iris.target
 
t= 1
for i in range (0,4):
    for j in range (0,4):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(4,4,t)
        ax.scatter(X[:, i], X[:, j], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
        t=t+1
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your for loop with the below one. Also, notice that I have placed plt.show outside for loop

```
for i in range (0,4):
     for j in range (0,4):
             ax = plt.subplot(4,4,t)
             ax.scatter(X[:, i], X[:, j], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
             t=t+1

plt.show()
```

Comment: great, thanks . That works - the matrix is crammed how can i increase the spaces and the size of each chart. Grateful if you could advice how can i replace scatter plots with histogram if i==j so that i can have histograms in the diagonal (is there any way i can iterate that than replacing case by case ) Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you are looking for jointplot ... why don't you import seaborn and use jointplot for plotting this...